# Como colocar propaganda em meu aplicativo pra Firefox OS

Tags: html5, firefox, app

Criei alguns aplicativos em HTML5 para Firefox OS, mas não consigo colocar propagandas para monetizá-lo.
Existe alguma ferramenta para isso?

Comment: Pode mostrar o que tentou? Chegou a pesquisar alguma coisa? Se tiver mais detalhes, por favor, **[edite](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/26691/edit)** a pergunta para acrescentá-los.

Answer (score 5):

Qualquer rede de publicidade que funciona num navegador vai funcionar no Firefox OS. Podes fazer uso de [Leadbolt](http://www.leadbolt.com/), [Inneractive](http://inner-active.com/) ou [Google Adsense](http://www.google.com/adsense/start/), entre outras.

**Nota:** o [membro hilty do HTML5 Game Devs Forum](http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/3852-firefox-os-and-ads/) colocou algumas reticências:

> 1. Leadbolt - Em algumas versões a publicidade não aparece
> 2. Inneractive - Demoram muito tempo a aprovar a conta
> 3. Google Adsense - Bloqueiam a publicidade de descobrem que está no Firefox OS

Claro que estas indicações podem ser ou não verdade actualmente, é preciso explorar cada caso.

---

## Monetização com Inneractive no Firefox OS

A rede Inneractive parece ser a que vai funcionar melhor, pelo menos com a informação disponível até à data.

A Mozilla tem uma biblioteca para integrar anúncios usando a rede Inneractive que se encontra detalhado no seguinte artigo:

#### [Monetization with Inneractive on Firefox OS](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2013/10/monetization-with-inneractive-on-firefox-os/)

Publicado em 31 Outubro 2013 por Louis Stowasser e Robert Nyman.

### Preparação

1. Descarregar a biblioteca a partir da [página da mesma no Github](https://github.com/mozilla/inneractive), onde irá ser particularmente necessário o ficheiro `inneractive.js`.
2. Incluir o ficheiro `inneractive.js` no teu HTML:

   ```
   <script src="inneractive.js"></script>
   ```
3. Criar uma [conta no Inneractive](https://console.inner-active.com/iamp/iamp/publisher/register). Uma vez aprovada, podes aceder à consola e registar a tua aplicação:

   [image: Imagem de Monetization with Inneractive on Firefox OS]

   Isso irá gerar um ID único "App ID" que pode ser encontrado na parte inferior do painel:

   [image: Imagem de Monetization with Inneractive on Firefox OS]

### Criar o Anúncio

A aplicação deverá ter acesso ao objeto global `Inneractive`. Podemos assim criar um anúncio com a função `createAd()`:

```
var myAd = Inneractive.createAd(options);
```

O objeto `options` permite-nos personalizar o anúncio. As opções disponíveis
são os seguintes:

- `APP_ID`

  O ID único da aplicação que já vimos como pode ser obtido na parte sobre "Preparação" presente nesta resposta.
- `TYPE`

  Pode ser um de três tipos de anúncios:

  - `Banner`

    Pequeno anúncio que é normalmente constante, na parte inferior do ecrã.
  - `Rectangle`

    Anúncio de tamanho médio que se encontra geralmente centrado no meio da tela.
  - `Interstitial`

    Anúncio Tela Cheia para exibir normalmente durante níveis de jogos ou telas de aplicações.
- `REFRESH_RATE`

  Tempo em segundos entre os anúncios rotativos. Mínima é de 15 segundos, o padrão é 30.

**Exemplo fazendo uso de opções:**

```js
var options = {
    TYPE: "Banner",
    REFRESH_RATE: 18,
    APP_ID: "Test_App_ID"
};

var myAd = Inneractive.createAd(options);
```

### Aplicar Anúncio

Uma vez criado o anúncio com as opções pretendidas, falta colocar o mesmo na tela.

A função `addTo()` permite colocar o anúncio na árvore do DOM sob um nó pai. Normalmente utilizando o `document.body` resolve-se bem a questão:

```js
myAd.addTo(document.body);
```

Isto irá colocar o anúncio sob o elemento `<body>` na página.

De seguida, precisamos posicionar o anúncio fazendo uso da função `placement()`.
Esta função recebe dois argumentos referentes à posição vertical e posição horizontal onde dispomos das seguintes opções:

- Posição vertical: `top`, `bottom` ou `center`
- Posição horizontal: `left`, `right`ou `center`

**Exemplos:**

Para um banner ficar na parte inferior da tela:

```js
myAd.placement("bottom", "center");
```

Um banner a aparecer exactamente no centro da tela:

myAd.placement("center", "center");

### Remover Anúncio

Se por qualquer motivo for necessário remover o anúncio da tela, podemos fazer uso da função `remove()`:

```js
myAd.remove();
```

Uma vez removido, não podemos voltar a utilizar o anúncio em questão.

É necessário fazer uso do objeto global `Inneractive` e proceder à criação de um novo anúncio:

```js
var myAd = Inneractive.createAd();
```

Comment: Só Funciona par Firefox OS ou para android e IOS também?